# detecting files Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to be able to loop through multiple different folders and check whether or not a file is present in said folder.

We have multiple business units, each with a folder, the sub-folder structure for each business unit is identical as they are all required to complete a monthly workbook with various data contained within it.

Firstly I have created a list of the relevant pathways, I've done this just using excel formula by concatenating the business unit folder name with the file path (with 1 variable being the month that is being checked) so I have a list of file pathways that look something like this `'D:\BusinessUnitA\April'`

There are 34 of them in the range `B2:B36` on a worksheet named `"Data"`.

At the moment the requirement is simply to loop through each of these folders and display the name of the file that is present in this folder, if not file then a message to say as much. I have written the following.

```
Sub checkfiles()

    Dim FilesList As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Filename As String
    
    
    Set FilesList = Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B36")
    
        For Each C In FilesList
            
        Set Filename = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(C & "*")
        
            If Filename = VBAemptystring Then
                MsgBox "No File Present", vbOKCancel
                
            Else
                MsgBox Filename, vbOKCancel
            
            End If
            
        Next C
    
End Sub
```

When running the code I get a compile error: "Object Required". My experience is in T-SQL and am fairly new to Excel VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change "Set Filename" to "Filename", string variable is not treated like an object and VBAemptystring  to vbnullstring

Answer (score 0):

As Filename is declared as a String, you should not use the "Set" keyword (in VBA it is used to set an object variable). The other problem is the VBAemptystring constant - it seems to me that it doesn't exist in Excel VBA. Maybe you can try using doubleqoutes:

```
Filename = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(C & "*")
        
    If Filename = "" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub checkfiles()

Dim FilesList As Variant
Dim FileExists As Boolean
Dim txtHeader As String:  txtHeader = "Following file:" & vbNewLine
Dim txt As String
Dim nameFile As String
Dim msgBoxAnswer As Variant

    ' read list to an array with transpose
    ' (it makes 2D array to 1D for a single column)
    FilesList = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B36").Value2)
    
    ' simply loop through the array 
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(FilesList) To UBound(FilesList)
        
        nameFile = FilesList(i)
        FileExists = Len(Dir(nameFile)) > 0
        
        txt = txtHeader & nameFile & vbNewLine & _
                   IIf(FileExists, "exists.", "does NOT exists!")

        msgBoxAnswer = MsgBox(txt, vbOKCancel)
        If msgBoxAnswer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub    

    Next i

End Sub
```

But IMO better idea would be display info at once, multiple MsgBoxes annoys me ;) Another thing: FileSystemObject is rather more reliable, simple Dir probably is not working on virtual locations (I am not sure, but I've read about problems with e.g. google drive folder on the board)

Answer (score -1):

Your code contains a number of newbie mistakes.

Try the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkfiles()

    ' create an array of paths from spreadsheet values
    Dim FilesList As Variant
    FilesList = Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B36").Value

    ' iterate over the values in Filelist.  myPath must be a variant or object type
    ' C was a poor name for the loop control variable so has been replaced with myPath.
    Dim myPath As Variant
    For Each myPath In FilesList
    
        Dim FileName As String
        FileName = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(myPath & "*")
        
        ' Use an immediate if to select between two simple variables.
        MsgBox IIf(Len(filename) = 0, "No File Present", FleName), vbOKOnly
            
    Next
    
End Sub
```